# Using Zurb's Foundation via NPM install

Tags: node.js, express, npm, zurb-foundation

I'm fairly new to using nodejs and npm, so please excuse any naivety.  I want to use Foundation in my latest project and use npm to get it installed. This has worked and my `node_modules` now contains the foundation dir.

How do I now use Foundation in my markup?  I have a `/public` dir which contains my views, but surely it would be bad practise to point references to the node_modules dir?  Do I create a custom route in `app.js` to files within the foundation dir?  I'm not sure what the best practise is?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something about NodeJS. NodeJS in a website is the backend like PHP, ASP or Ruby.

Foundation Framework is a CSS framework, so it's for the client, the frontend.

To use it in a website running by NodeJS, just put the library that you downloaded in [Zurb website](http://foundation.zurb.com/) in the public directory and use it in your views like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foundation.css">
```

Comment: So I can't use npm to get the latest version of Foundation?  Do I just move the necessary files from node_modules to my public (from server to client) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to get it by npm. NPM is for the server and your library is for the client.

Comment: Ah it uses Stylus. Do you use Stylus or prefer CSS ?

Comment: I want to use it with Stylus :)

Comment: Do you use Express ? Because it has an intern module to interpret Stylus. So with that, you just need to get the Stylus Foundation version, not all the package

Comment: thanks, I got it working in the end. I simply put the foundation files in my `public/css` dir. The mistake was using npm to pull it down.

Comment: For anyone wanting to use a package manager like NPM, use Bower (bower.io) for client components.  Technically there is nothing wrong with asking how Foundation can be pulled from NPM as it does have a JavaScript library.  Also, if someone is using something like browserify, it's not a crazy question to see if Foundation could be loaded via NPM.  One more thing, Node is not like PHP, ASP or Ruby, that would be JavaScript, Node as a website backend is more akin to Apache or Nginx as for that purpose you are using it for a webserver.

Comment: @RobBennet Actually it's more comparable to PHP, ASP or Ruby. Apache and Nginx are web servers while node.js is just used as a web server by most. While it is true that it is running as a server(a VP8 interpreter of JavaScript code), you could do only local operations like accessing files, starting processes without having anything to do with the web.

Answer (score 8):

You need register foundation as a stylus plugin. If you are using connect or express try something like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    app = express();

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    compile: function (str, path) {
        return stylus(str)
            .set('filename', path)
            .use(require('foundation')());
    }
}));
```

Then in your styl file you can

```
@import "foundation"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Installing Foundation with npm

```
npm install foundation-sites
```

Then, copy Foundation's files to your web server and reference it with a `<link>` tag.

### Installing Foundation with Bower

```
bower install foundation
```

Then, copy Foundation's files (or the entire bower_components directory) to your web server and reference it with a `<link>` tag.

---

Foundation's [GitHub page](https://github.com/zurb/foundation) and their [Getting Started page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/index.html) has more information on the different ways to set up Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to pull in the foundation code.  git://github.com/ch1c0t/bower-foundation-css.git OR git://github.com/mmcgahan/sass-foundation.git.  Bower is a client side package manager similar to npm, but for the client. http://bower.io/